# How to translate several php files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, translate

I´m developing a website with several php files using a xml file with the translations. The aim is that the user choose the desired language in the first page and then all the others pages appears with the selected language.

I´m using this file idioma.js to receive the selected id of the language and read the xml file to translate.

```
$('input').click(function() {
    language = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: 'validarporto.php',
        data: {
            'language': language
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert("---"+data);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'traducao.xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('traducao').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var text = $(this).find(language).text();
                $("." + id).html(text);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This function is called with onclick, by pressing a button with the desired language. This is working fine.

Those are the buttons to choose the language in my index.php

```
  <form method="post" name='idioma' id='idioma'>
    <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary sharp outline" onclick='function()'value='PT' id='pt' name='pt'></input>
    <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary sharp outline" onclick='function()'value='EN' id='en' name='en'></input>
    <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary sharp outline" onclick='function()'value='ES' id='es' name='es'></input>
  </form>
```

The problem is now. I need to save that id and pass it to next php file to automatic translate the page to the user without forcing the user to click another time in the button.

and there is a little bit of my traducao.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<traducoes>
    <traducao id='titulo1'>
        <pt>A melhor maneira de conhecer o melhor do Porto!</pt>
        <en>The best way to know the best in Porto!</en>
        <es>La mejor manera de experimentar lo mejor de Porto!</es>
    </traducao>
    <traducao id='titulo2'>
        <pt>Entradas gratuitas e descontos em mais de 100 atrações.</pt>
        <en>Free entries and discounts at over 100 attractions.</en>
        <es>Entrada gratuita y descuentos en más de 100 lugares de interés.</es>
    </traducao>
    <traducao id='titulo3'>
        <pt>Conheça mais, poupe mais!</pt>
        <en>Learn more, save more!</en>
        <es>Obtenga más, ahorrar más!</es>
    </traducao>
```

Comment: the other alterantive is to just use a cookie. but please a dictionary in which you document all cookies you make use of for a webapplaiction, and what their meaning is to have this documented with your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the port is validated (first Ajax request), on the response why don't you call the next function?

```
$('input').click(function () 
{
  language=$(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:'validarporto.php',
    data: {'language':language},
    success: function(data){
      //alert("---"+data);
      nextstep(language);
    }
  });

function nexstep(language){
      $.ajax
  ({
    url:'traducao.xml',
    success:function(xml)
    {
      $(xml).find('traducao').each(function()
      {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var text = $(this).find(language).text();
        $("."+ id).html(text);
      });
    }
  });
}

});
```

Comment: How do i make to call the second function when the next php file is called?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the language id in a $_SESSION variable the first time you click on the button, so you can access to it later.

Comment: I´ve tried that, but then i can´t make the automatic translation.

Comment: If you are accessing the XML with javascript, then just save the language id in the local storage using localStorage.setItem("language_id", language_id) or in a cookie, so you can access to it in every page.

Comment: I´m new at this and i´m not even sure if this is the right way to make the translation. Can you explain me a little better how to do it?

Comment: You could have 3 php files (each one for a different language), and there defining constants for the content of the page. For example in pt.php: define("titulo1","A melhor maneira de conhecer o melhor do Porto!");
So depending on which language the user has chosen, you load right translation file. The first time the user chooses the language just save the language id in session, and  use it to load the translation file.